# Is there a way to make a Foundation column exceed the boundaries of it's row?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-6

I am using Zurb Foundation 6. I have a row with 2 columns, as such:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="columns medium-4 left-col">
     Left column.
   </div>
   <div class="columns medium-8 right-col">
     Right column. Needs to reach far right hand side of screen.
   </div>
</div>
```

Naturally, Foundation `.row`s have a max-width of 75rem, meaning there will be margins either side if the screen is larger than 75rem. That's fine, I want to leave that. However, I want the right side column to extend all the way to the right, passed that 75rem width.

In other words, I want to try and have the left column behave like its within a `max-width: 75rem;` wrapping row, but the right column to behave like it's in a `max-width: 100%;` wrapping row.

See here for more info: https://jsfiddle.net/u4x5owc0/11/

Is there a way I can achieve this (with Foundation)?

I've tried making the right column `position: absolute; width: 100%;` but that just covers the left side as well.

Would anyone know if this is possible and if theres a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think foundation has this feature but using `position: absolute; right: 0;` on the right column worked for me.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by5ekwta/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.right-col{position: absolute; right: 0;}`. But it won't support for small devices. You should use `@media` query for responsive. Please check [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u4x5owc0/13/) it's working fine with responsive.

```css
.left-col, .right-col {
  height: 40vh;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left-col {
  background: green;
}

.right-col {
  background: red;
}
@media(min-width:640px){
  .right-col{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="columns medium-4 left-col">
</div>
<div class="columns medium-8 right-col">
Needs to reach far right hand side of screen. ==>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row expanded">
<div class="columns medium-4 left-col">
  Needs to remain the same width as above. 
</div>
<div class="columns medium-8 right-col">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close! The issue is that the right col takes up 66.67% of the entire screen width, and so actually covers the left col, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/u4x5owc0/15/

Comment: I just checked Zurb Foundation 6. They clearly mentioned the width and responsive in details. Please go through this link. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html
If you still have any issue please comment here.